# How can I uppercase and lowercase a Char

Tags: java, gwt

GWT is not allowing me to use `Character.toUpperCase(char)` and `Character.toLowerCase(char)`. How can I rewrite the method bellow to not use the `Character` class or any external library

```
public static String toDisplayCase(String s) {

    final String ACTIONABLE_DELIMITERS = " '-/"; // these cause the character following
                                                 // to be capitalized

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean capNext = true;

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        c = (capNext)
                ? Character.toUpperCase(c)
                : Character.toLowerCase(c);
        sb.append(c);
        capNext = (ACTIONABLE_DELIMITERS.indexOf((int) c) >= 0); // explicit cast not needed
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: XY problem, maybe?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The `Character` class is part of the GWT [emulation layer](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_lang).

Comment: Do you get a compilation error or is there an exception thrown?

Comment: Are you accidentally using a Character class from a library other than java.lang?

Comment: just tested Character methods in GWT 2.8 app and all works fine. What is the problem you have?

Comment: Are you sure that GWT is not allowing you....? I guess your teacher is not allowing you. But looking at your reputation, that too seems quite unlikely.

Comment: Works just fine here when using GWT 2.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If somehow, you are not allowed to use Character class (though that sounds quite crazy), you may add or subtract ASCII values.

eg:

```
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    c = (capNext)
            ?  ( (c>='a'&&c<='z') ? c+32 : c) //to Upper Case
            :  ( (c>='A'&&c<='Z') ? c-32 : c) //to Lower Case
    sb.append(c);
    capNext = (ACTIONABLE_DELIMITERS.indexOf((int) c) >= 0); // explicit cast not needed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use basic operators

```
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    c = c - 'a' + 'A';  // lower to upper
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    c = c - 'A' + 'a';  // upper to lower
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are toLower and toUpper using ascii values. Hope it helps.

```
static char toUpperCase(char c) {
    if (97 <= c && c <= 122) {
        c = (char) ((c - 32));
    }
    return c;
}

static char toLowerCase(char c) {
    if (65 <= c && c <= 90) {
        c = (char) ((c + 32));
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Checkstyle does not like magic numbers and me neither. So I suggest to replace these 6 integers with constants.

Comment: This is not full working example you know. If the Author decides to use this approach as his final solution he can tweak it whatever he likes.